# difference between a primary key attribute and other attributes in a table

Tags: sql

What is the difference between a primary key and an attribute which is declared as **UNIQUE** and **NOT NULL** in the same table in a database?

Comment: You can only have one primary key per table.

Comment: also u might want to read the second comment in the above duplicate link ;)

Comment: Logically speaking there is no difference. In practice there may be some subtle differences depending on your DBMS software - usually to do with internal storage and indexing.

Answer (score 3):

There can only be one **primary key** in a table and that cannot be null. You dont have to explicitly specify the **NOT NULL** attribute for primary key.

There can be more than one **unique key** in the table. Unique key can be null

When you specify any column as **NOT NULL** then it means that you cannot leave the column as NULL

**EDIT:-**

As per your comments, you cannot have more than one **primary key** in your table.

Also a unique key constraint does not imply the NOT NULL constraint in practice. Besides what is the use of writing **NOT NULL** for unique key as that is the only difference between Primary key and Unique key.

Comment: if we specify a unique key as not null then does it serve same as primary key??and can we have more than one primary key in a table..

Comment: thank you Mr.Rahul i got it now

Comment: You are abusing the term "key" here. By definition no key (i.e. candidate key) may permit null values. If a column permits nulls then it definitely isn't a *key* column, whether or not it has a UNIQUE constraint on it. So it's right to say that there can be more than one key in a table but wrong to say that a key can be null.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that that SQL constraint was named **primary key** because it confuses the *related but different* concepts of the *Logical Entity primary key* and the *Physical Storage primary key* of the entity. While it is certainly possible, and not infrequently the case, that the same fields are used for both the logical and physical *primary key*, this is not required and also frequently not desirable.

The *Logical Entity primary key* is the object referred to in Database textbooks discussing relational theory. It is this object that one refers to when *Normalizing* relation structures, and it is (of course) one of the candidate keys that exist for the Entity in the logical model.

The *Physical Storage primary key* is an attribute in the *Physical Model*, **possibly in addition to** those attributes defined in the Logical Model for the Entity, which is used by the DBMS to uniquely identify the **storage** for an instance of the Logical Entity. This is the object being referred to in the *primary key constraint* when defining the (physical) schema for an entity's storage. When this *Physical Storage primary key* differs from the *Logical Entity primary key* it is most commonly because an artificial key has been appended to the logical attributes in order to:

- Enable update of fields in the *Logical Entity primary key*;
- Improve performance by being a narrower key for *foreign key* reference refer to

All *Logical Entity candidate keys* should be defined in the Physical Model with uniqueness constraints. Only the *Physical Storage primary key* becomes the **primary key** constraint.

Comment: The idea of "primary key" being a physical storage feature predates the relational model. The relational and SQL usage of the term is under discussion here and that's strictly a *logical*, not physical construct. It would be more accurate to say that some SQL DBMSs unwisely use the *logical* primary key as a cue for certain physical storage features, thus compromising the principle of physical data independence. This isn't universally the case however and it's a bad idea to assume that physical always follows logical; even worse to assume that logical ought to follow physical.

Comment: @sqlvogel: My point is that the two concepts are distinct, are often not the same set of attributes, and should thus be referred to by distinct names to avoid confusion. It is not clear to me whether you are agreeing or disagreeing.

Comment: PRIMARY KEY is not two concepts in a SQL DBMS because keys are a logical feature not physical. That is what I was disagreeing with. On re-reading your answer however, I think I understand that what you mean by "logical" is a *preliminary design* for a database table and what you mean by "physical" is an *implementation* of a database table. Is that right? I recommend you be very careful using such terms on SO because they often lead to confusion. In database-theoretic terms keys and tables are always logical features of a database.

Comment: @sqlvogel: EXACTLY! Yet the DBMS (ie physical) constraint is called the **primary key** constraint, which is a confusion of terms. I may not be completely up-to-date on the terminology, but was proposing one alternate terminology that would eliminate the confusion; and allow both more lucid thinking and clearer communication.